# Synchronizing two tablets from QField

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

I have two tablets with QField on it, on which I load the same QGIS Project. The Fieldworkes go record points in the field. After that I want to synchronize both tablets back to my QGIS Project via QSync. After the first synchronization I've got the message: `"CRITICAL Data from this file are already synchronized with the original project"`.
Both the tablets have the same data on it but the fieldworkers record the points in different areas.

Does anyone have an idea how I can syncronize two tablets?

Comment: have you set your point (?) layer as offline editable?